# Como puedo correr php en React

Tags: php, reactjs, email

Veran, estoy haciendo un pequeño portafolio con React JS y he pensado en implementar un pequeño formulario de contacto el cual pueda enviar emails, el problema es que no entiendo muy bien como hacer una conexion entre React y PHP

Este es mi componente

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

import { TweenMax, Power3, TimelineMax } from "gsap";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const Contact = () => {
const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
let contact = useRef(null);
const [Animation, setAnimation] = useState(false);
const tl = new TimelineMax();

useEffect(() => {
 TweenMax.from(contact.current.childNodes, 1, {
  delay: 1,
  y: "100px",
  opacity: 0,
  ease: Power3.easeOut,
  stagger: {
    amount: 0.5,
  },
});
});

const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
 console.log(data);
 e.target.reset();
 setAnimation(true);
 setInterval(setAnimation(false), 2000)
};

useEffect(() => {
if(Animation){
  tl.to(contact.current.childNodes[4], 1, {
    delay: 1,
    y: "100%",
    ease: Power3.easeOut,
    stagger: {
      amount: 0.1,
    },
  }).to(contact.current.childNodes[4], 1, {
    delay: 1,
    y: "-100%",
    ease: Power3.easeOut,
    stagger: {
      amount: 0.1,
    },
  });
}
})



return (
    <div className="contact" ref={contact}>
      <h3>
        Hey! Let me a message to keep <span>in touch.</span>
      </h3>
      <form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          autoComplete="off"
          placeholder="Name"
          ref={register}
          required
        />
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          autoComplete="off"
          placeholder="Email"
          ref={register}
          required
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="subject"
          autoComplete="off"
          placeholder="Subject"
          ref={register}
          required
        />
        <textarea
          type="text"
          name="message"
          autoComplete="off"
          placeholder="Message"
          ref={register}
          required
        />
        <button type="submit">SEND</button>
      </form>
      <h4>Look also my Git</h4>
      <a href="https://github.com/Sebastian-Mat">
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="28"
          height="28"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          fill="none"
          stroke="currentColor"
          strokeWidth="1"
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
        >
          <path d="M9 19c-5 1.5-5-2.5-7-3m14 6v-3.87a3.37 3.37 0 0 0-.94-2.61c3.14-.35 6.44-1.54 6.44-7A5.44 5.44 0 0 0 20 4.77 5.07 5.07 0 0 0 19.91 1S18.73.65 16 2.48a13.38 13.38 0 0 0-7 0C6.27.65 5.09 1 5.09 1A5.07 5.07 0 0 0 5 4.77a5.44 5.44 0 0 0-1.5 3.78c0 5.42 3.3 6.61 6.44 7A3.37 3.37 0 0 0 9 18.13V22"></path>
        </svg>
      </a>
      <div className="modal">
        <h1>Thanks for the message</h1>
        <h2>We will in touch!</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

Mi idea es recoger la data del formulario y pasarla a un archivo php que envie el correo, el problema es que estoy aprendiendo esto de React y no se muy bien como hacer esa conexion o ejecutar la funcion dentro del archivo (aún no tengo el archivo php en el proyecto, porque no se donde debo ubicarlo).
Estaria muy agradecido por cualquier ayuda y recomendacion que puedan brindarme.

Comment: React es JS y PHP se ejecuta en el servidor, me parece todo se reduce a qué envíes vía Ajax del form a tu PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con AJAX, de una manera, simple

Puedes hacer que, al presionar un botón llame una función

```html
<button onclick="enviarEmail()">Enviar</button>
```

```javascript
const enviarEmail = () => {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('mensaje', 'Hola mundo');
    // Añade la información a enviar con POST con data.append
    fetch('tuarchivo.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
    }).then(function(response) {
       response.text().then(resp => {
          console.log(resp) // Respuesta del backend
      });
    })
}
```

Usaremos un `FormData` para enviar la información que necesitamos

Si vas a recibir una respuesta JSON (NO string), con un `header` especificando que el `Content-Type` es JSON, puedes usar `.json()` en vez de `.text()`

Y `.text()` es por si vas a recibir una respuesta en texto

Fetch es un manera de hacer llamadas AJAX, es soportado desde `ES6` y compatible con TODOS los navegadores

Además, como te dijeron en los comentarios, no puedes ejecutar PHP desde el cliente, esta es una forma, ReactJS se ejecuta desde el cliente y PHP desde el servidor, no hay manera de que puedas ejecutar PHP desde React a menos que cambies tu extensión y añadas un header para especificar que el archivo será leído como JavaScript

Ejemplo:

Cambiando la extensión desde `.js` a `.php`

```php
<?php
    $miVar = "Hola mundo";
    header("Content-Type: text/javascript"); // Aquí especificas que tu archivo será leído como JavaScript
?>
console.log("<?php print $miVar; ?>")
```

Si tienes problemas de CORS, puedes hacer lo siguiente

```javascript
const enviarEmail = () => {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('mensaje', 'Hola mundo');
    // Añade la información a enviar con POST con data.append
    fetch('tuarchivo.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data,
        mode:"no-cors"
    }).then(function(response) {
       response.text().then(resp => {
          console.log(resp) // Respuesta del backend
      });
    })
}
```

Tienes que añadir `no-cors` así harás que el servidor ignore el CORS y la petición sea exitosa

Comment: Convendría que tú respuesta sea más amplia, por ejemplo ahí para que usas `FormData`?

Comment: Además cual sería la diferencia entre `response.text()` o `.json()`

Comment: Para poder hacer el Fetch necesito correr algun entorno como XAMPP?, ya que cuando corro el codigo me da este error "Contact.jsx:28 POST http://localhost/api/Send.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED", ademas si corro XAMPP tambien me da un error pero esta vez con "CORS". Tambien lo intente hacer desde axios pero me sigue dando los mismos errores.

Comment: @Sebastian Si te da un error de CORS añade en la primera línea de tu PHP (depués de abrir la etiqueta php) `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://tudominio.com")` o `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")`

Comment: @anythingg me sigue saliendo el error de CORS "has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.", y ya coloque el header en el archivo php

Comment: @Sebastian Prueba con el código añadido en la edición

Comment: @anythingg agregandole eso me sigue dando este error "Contact.jsx:30 POST http://localhost:8080/Email.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: @Sebastian asegúrate que el puerto está bien, y que el protocolo también, si el puerto está mal puede ser motivo del error

Comment: @anythingg esa parte si no estoy seguro de como abordarla, esta fue la ruta que coloque "http://localhost:8080/Email.php", en eso de los puertos si no tengo experencia :(

Comment: ¿Si entras a http://localhost:8080/ carga? Si no carga tienes que poner después de los dos puntos el puerto que tienes configurado en tu servidor (En este caso has puesto 8080) Si solo accedes con http://localhost/ el puerto es 80

Comment: @anythingg el puerto 8080 es que se me ejecuta cuando abro XAMPP, el puerto 3000 se ejecuta cuando abro la app React, cuando ejecuto XAMPP y despues la app me sale ese error (solo si en la app en el apartado donde tengo que poner la ruta coloco localhost:8080), si no abro xampp me dice que no encuentra el archivo, y con el puerto 3000 tambien me da error. Perdon si no me exprese muy bien o si no entienden mucho :(

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a todos los que me ayudaron, he conseguido con su ayuda y un poco de pruebas lograr enviar la info al php. Basicamente se me olvido que XAMPP ejecuta los archivos que se encuentren en una carpeta llamada htdocs y mi archivo php no se encontraba ahi, lo que hice fue mover la carpeta en donde estaba el archivo php a htdocs y colocar esto en el php

```
<?php
    
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if($method == "OPTIONS") {

    die();

}
```

Ya luego ejecuto XAMPP y corro la app y obtengo respuesta del php.
Muchisimas gracias por su atencion :)